# Are there deep design reasons for Foundation collections' inability to store nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, null, foundation

Everyone knows that Foundation collections like `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSSet` can't store `nil` objects, and that you have to use `NSNull` instead. I'm sure if I dug into the open-source Core Foundation source code, I could even find where that's enforced.

What I don't understand is, *why* are they designed this way? Is it purely because `nil` is used as a sentinel in some of their constructors, or is there a deeper reason for this behavior?

Comment: Nil is not an object. Collections can only store reference types, you can use the NSValue wrapper class for that (i.e. to store CGRects, etc). Or you can use NSNull in your case.

Comment: @JayMorgan: Right, and `nil` is a value of every reference type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you'll get a satisfactory answer to this. It is just a design decision, like a thousand others that shaped Cocoa. Even if the people who originally made the decision back in the day were to show up and explain, the explanation would always necessarily boil down to "it's what seemed best to us". That is, it's clearly *possible* to design and implement collection classes that can hold `nil` and any justification for not supporting that is going to be contestable. Somebody will object that the justification doesn't make sense to them vs. the justification for doing it the other way. At that point it's just subjective judgment.

That said, here are a couple of issues:

- Suppose `[dict objectForKey:@"myKey"]` returns `nil`. Is that because `nil`
  was added as the value for `@"myKey"` or because no value was added
  for that key?
- Dictionaries and sets (and even `NSArray` methods like `-containsObject:` and `-indexOfObject:`) use `-isEqual:` to test object equality. However, `[nil isEqual:anything]` will always return false. Therefore, you'd never be able to find `nil` in the collection. You could overcome this with extra checks for `nil`, but that a) violates the design contract that `-isEqual:` is used to determine equality, and b) imposes implementation costs.
- Methods like `-lastObject`, `-firstObject`, and `-anyObject` return `nil` when there are no objects in the collection. How do you distinguish that from returning a `nil` that's a member of the collection? Similarly, for `-[NSEnumerator nextObject]`.

Comment: The `isEqual` case is a good reason to support the *choice*. For the other cases a different sentinel value could be used.

Comment: The `-isEqual:` and `NSEnumerator` points are particularly illuminating. Thank you.

Comment: Collections in the Java collections framework allow `null`, and can address each of your issues above. 1) In Java, there is also no way to tell from the result of `Map.get()` whether the value is `null` or key is not there. That's why there's a method `containsKey()`. `NSDictionary` can have a similar method. In fact, `CFDictionary` I believe allows `NULL`, and indeed has a `CFDictionaryContainsKey` function to check for a key. 2) The contract can be changed to handle `nil`. Java's `Collection.contains` contract checks for `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Comment: (continued) 3) Java's `Iterator` has a `hasNext()` method to check whether there is another element, and calling `next` when there isn't throws an exception. `NSEnumerator` can be changed to add a method to check whether there's more, and/or throw an exception when getting next when there isn't more.

Comment: @newacct, congratulations on demonstrating the point of my first paragraph!